# How to use setTop() for a LinearLayout

Tags: android

I want to put a LineatLayout to the bottom of the screen.
This LineraLayout is inside his parent Linearlayout.
I get the height of the screen  and accordig to it, i know what value put inside setTop().
But setTop() doens't do anything.
I use setTop after clicking a button, not in the onCreate method, so the main layout is fully loaded.

I tried to use
 `LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);`
but there's not setTop method in this case.

This is my layout now [image]

this is what i'd like to achieve

[image]

This is a part of my xml file

```
<!-- parent-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@xml/background_generale"
    android:gravity="top|right|center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <!-- child-->
        <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/layoutBottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/mainLayoutRaddoppiaBackground"
        android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

       ...here there are the 4 buttons you can see in the image...


       <!-- end child-->
        </LinearLayout> 

<!-- end parent-->
 </LinearLayout>
```

What should i do?

Comment: Can't you use the Gravity?

Comment: You may try RelativeLayout for the parent layout.

Comment: Layout_weight can get you your result. Also post some xml snippet and your desired layout as result.

Comment: I can't, because if i turn LinearLayout into Relativelayout i have to re-design all the object i have in the page

Comment: I can't use the gravity because, ad you can see in the image, all of my element must be placed to the top of the parent LinearLayout. Only the child LinearLayout, you can see it in the image, must stay to the bottom of the parent Linearlayout

Comment: @Avinazz i don't get. How should i use it?

Answer (score 0):

```
parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,   
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
parms.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

This should place the element at the bottom of it's parent. If you want the layout to fill the entirety of it's parent, try changing `WRAP_CONTENT` to `MATCH_PARENT`. But the part that actually aligns your layout at the top is the `rule` I added.

Answer (score 0):

See if this layout helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/holo_grey"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@color/blue_dark" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="openAdmin"
        android:text="ABC" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="openTasks"
        android:text="XYZ" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@color/blue_dark" >
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Its a sample layout.Put all your contents in "llContent" layout.